# BungeeChat TextComponent Chat Bug

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I was making a confirmation Text Component with Bungee Chat ClickEvent for my plugin, the only way to send it to the player that worked for me was using `player.sendMessage("" + message)` without throwing any error. But if I try to show the text in Minecraft, it happens this. [image]

My full class code is:

```java
package plugin;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.ClickEvent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent;

public class InfoCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    public TextComponent TextComponent;
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmnd, String alias, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            return false;
        }
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.sendMessage("Some confirmation text.");
        TextComponent yes = new TextComponent("Yes");
        yes.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/warp info"));
        
        player.sendMessage("[          " + yes + "          ]");
        return true;
    }
}
```

What's the cause of that and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't any error. Is simply that we need to use the BungeeChat API and **also** the Spigot API (Not the Bukkit API).

For future reference, to solve the problem, we only need to follow this steps:

1. Download the Spigot API for your plugin version [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/) (or add the Spigot API to your pom.xml if you are using Maven)
2. In your IDE, create a new library and assign your Spigot jar. After that, add the library to your project.
3. Make sure that Bukkit is propertly imported (`import org.bukkit.*whatever*;`)

That should solve the problem.